# How can I get multiple input for optional phone number dynamically (DOM)?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, bootstrap-5

*Here is my code. I want to add more phone number as optional phone. How can I do it dinamically?*

```
          <div class="col-12 row border my-2 py-2">
                <div class="col-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label " for="official_phone"><h5 class="h6">Phone (Official) *</h5></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="official_phone" placeholder="Input Phone Number.." required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label " for="optional_phone"><h5 class="h6">Phone (Others) </h5></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="optional_phone" placeholder="Input Phone Number.."/>
                </div>
                
            </div>
```

Comment: Just add a button and link a event listener to the button where if the button is clicked, append another <div class="form-group"> into the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a button that triggers the input div into the parent form.

```js
let count = 1;
function addphone(){
    const parent = document.getElementById("phone-list");
    let el = document.createElement("div");
    el.setAttribute("class","col-6 form-group");
    el.innerHTML = `<label class="control-label " for="optional_phone_${count}"><h5 class="h6">Phone (Optional) *</h5></label><input class="form-control" type="text" name="optional_phone_${count}" placeholder="Input Phone Number.." required/>`;
    parent.appendChild(el);
  count++;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>
  <div class="col-12 row border my-2 py-2">
    <div id="phone-list">
      <div class="col-6 form-group">
        <label class="control-label " for="official_phone"><h5 class="h6">Phone (Official) *</h5></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="official_phone" placeholder="Input Phone Number.." required/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 form-group">
        <label class="control-label " for="optional_phone"><h5 class="h6">Phone (Others)</h5></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="optional_phone" placeholder="Input Phone Number.."/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="addphone()">Add Phone</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```